# Spring Boot sample Rest web service getting 403 error on Weblogic

Tags: java, spring, web-services, weblogic, weblogic-10.x

I'm deploying a .war file built from one of the Spring Boot Getting Started projects, built with Spring Tool Suite. It's a simple RESTful webservice that works on the Tomcat server provided in the Spring Tool Suite running on my PC. The service responds with a string property on a get operation, so it's simple.

I added the Web Fragment Module facet in order to generate a war file. I'm deploying this war to a Weblogic 10.3.5  managed server instance on a test host. The deployment is successful. However, when I use the test URL provided from the Weblogic admin console, I get a 403 forbidden error.

This basic war does not have a web.xml. Should I have one? Should it contain a welcome file reference?

Is there additional configuration that I should do on Weblogic? I am reading the Weblogic documentation.

Comment: Did you check [this](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html#howto-weblogic)?

Comment: I have not. Will do. Thanks.